# How to paste data to word doc

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am using send-keys to select all data and copy it from another application. My goal is to paste this data into word and save as a PDF. The problem i seem to have, is that using Microsoft interop, requires you to programattically format the data. If i copy the data from the other application, and paste it manually in a real word doc, the format retains itself.

Is there a way to easily take my clipboard data and use it with this code?

```
Try
            Dim oWord As Word.Application
            Dim oDoc As Word.Document



            'Start Word and open the document template.
            oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            oWord.Visible = True
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
            oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
            oPara1.Range.Text = Clipboard.SetText

            'TIll Above your entire odoc is formatted
            'From below I will save it to my own code

            Dim newdoc As Word.Document
            newdoc = oDoc
            newdoc.SaveAs2("K:\file.pdf", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)

            'All done. Close this form.
            'BSPGlobals.DataBase.Contact.ExitApp()
            MessageBox.Show("Print to Doc Done.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error at Printing the bill." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the source and format of the Clipboard data, you can influence the way the Clipboard contents is pasted into Word by fiddling around with the following `Application` options (don't forget to restore the original settings when you are done):

```vb
' when pasting between different Office documents     
oWord.Options.PasteFormatBetweenDocuments = Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting

' when contents is copied from a document that uses styles 
oWord.Options.PasteFormatBetweenStyledDocuments = Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting

' when pasting from an external source such as a web page   
oWord.Options.PasteFormatFromExternalSource = Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting
```